# I want to delete some empty <p> tags using php in xml file

Tags: php

I want to replace some empty `p` tags while creating xml file.

```
                    <p> <br> </p> 
                      <p> </p>
```

I used `str_replace`. That is not working we have to remove that one dynamically. Maybe we can use `preg_replace` for that .
[image]
Can you please write that `preg_replace` expression to me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions: use this regex to remove empty paragraph

Try

```
$data = // your html data
$pattern = "/<p[^>]*><\\/p[^>]*>/"; 
$data = preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);
```

To replace all empty tags:

```
$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/";
```

Comment: it's not working.if i use above expression it's showing <p/> ...it's now removing completely

Comment: <p/> is not a valid html tag, </p> is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You really should look at not putting the empty `<p>`s in the XML file in the first place.

But, in case that is not possible, you can replace `<p></p>` tags with optional whitespace and `<br>` tags inside, like this:

```
$data  = '[...]'
$attr  = '(?:\s+[\w\d\-]+\s*=\s*(["\'])(?:\\\\1|[^\\1])+\\1)*\s*';
$regex = "~<p{$attr}>(?:\s+|<br\s*/?>)*</p>~i";

// Replace empty paragraphs with optional
// whitespace and <br> inside it
$data  = preg_replace($regex, '', $data);
```

**Edit:**

If you just want to remove a paragraph with a space in it, then:

```
$data = 'asd <p> </p> asd';
$data = str_replace('<p> </p>', '', $data);
```

Comment: in xml,I just replace empty p tag with space... i have to remove that one

Comment: it's not working.if i use above expression it's showing <p/> ...it's now removing completely @  Sverri M. Olsen

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = preg_replace("/<p[^>]*>\s*<\/p[^>]*>/i", "", $data);
```